# getting stack overflow during return page from spring mvc controller

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have spring mvc controller, contain method like

```
@requestmapping("jsps/welcome.jsp")
public String handleRequest(){
system.out.println("inside the handler");
return "welcome";}
```

when I am trying to run the welcome.jsp page, I am getting stack overflow, it seems like the page is going to the controller then the controller return the page then it will go again and so on.

my configuration for spring is

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
class="------"
<property name="prefix">
<value> /jsps/ </value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value> .jsp </value>
</property>
```

and the urlmapping

```
<map>
<entry key="jsps/welcome.jsp">
<ref bean="mycontroller"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things

1. For URL mapping, better not to use *.jsp. Use something like jsps/welcome or jsps/welcome.htm
2. To return a view use [ModelAndVeiw](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html).

**UPDATE**

Make these changes

```
@requestmapping("jsps/welcome")
public String handleRequest(){
system.out.println("inside the handler");
return new ModelAndView("yourpathtojspfile");} // can be "jsps/welcome"
```

Here, this page will return the view (with 'jsps/welcome' you will get welcome.jsp)

When you return a string, the option you have is  to use

```
return "redirect:someUrl"; //But this will not return a view, instead search for the mapping someUrl.
```

Comment: when I am trying to remove the .jsp , I am getting no mapping found :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Controller is returning string `"welcome"` and view resolver is modifying it to `"jsps/welcome.jsp"` this is again calling the method.

change `@requestmapping("jsps/welcome.jsp")` to something other. Usually we have `welcome.htm` something like this

and then hit `welcome.htm` it will call the `handleRequest` method, method will return `"welcome"` and view resolver coverts it to `"jsps/welcome.jsp"`.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is obvious. A request to `jsps/welcome.jsp` calls the controller method, which forwards to a view named "welcome", which is resolved to url `jsps/welcome.jsp` again, calling the method again. So it goes on untill StackOverFlow is thrown.

Solution is to change url mapping to another `url without .jsp` like

```
@Requestmapping("/welcome")
public String handleRequest(){
   system.out.println("inside the handler");
   return "welcome";
}
```